# Which emulator support for all phones

Tags: android, screen, fullscreen

I am new for android application. I create a full screen new login page in android. It's working correctly in my tablet. But other phones text view and edit box position changed. Please help me to solve this...

Comment: You should really study [this](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should support your application into mltiples devices screens (if you want to run your app in different devices )

You can learn from this [official link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) **(Supporting Multiple Screens)** and [this link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html) **(Supporting Different Screens)**

The change of editText' position is normal , because you have made one layout ,you should create Different Layouts.

**Example :**

```
res/
        layout/              # default (portrait)
            main.xml
        layout-land/         # landscape
            main.xml
        layout-large/        # large (portrait)
            main.xml
        layout-small         # small screen
            main.xml
```